# WinForms - Enable button on AsyncCallback from a separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am VERY new to multi-threading and, so, am sure it's quite possible my entire question is wrong, but this is more for me to learn how things get done right, so I hope you'll forgive and ANY explanation set at an "idiot" level would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Suppose I have the following class external to my WinForm:

```
public class test
{
    public void RunOnSeparateThread()
    {
        // Some function that takes an AsyncCallback as a parameter and runs Asynchronously
        // Returns IAsyncResult
        foo(m_asyncCallback);
    }

    private AsyncCallback m_asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(AsyncComplete);
    private static void AsyncComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    { 
        // Whatever disposal stuff needs to be done, etc.
    }
}
```

---

Now, what I would like to do is have a button on my winform, that, when pressed:

1. Disables the button
2. Runs the `RunOnSeparateThread` process on a separate thread (not tie up the GUI thread)

Then, when the Async process is complete:

1. Have the `AsyncComplete` method run in the `Test` class
2. Re-enable the button on the form (and maybe some other things too in the `Form` class)

As I said, this is all brand new to me. What I'm imagining could be done would be to create an AsyncCallback delegate on the form and pass it to my class (as a property??) and have the `AsyncComplete` method run that at the end, but it seems like that could be very bad programming.

What is the best / correct way to do this - PLEASE understand I'm a major newbie on this kind of stuff, so I'd really appreciate any links / explanations so as to understand the correct way to multi-thread for a scenario such as this.

Also, although this is written in C#, I'm equally comfortable in VB and C#, so any answer would be greatly appreciated.

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of outdated `APM` approach unless your requirements are to use old .Net framework versions. But back to the question. Most UI frameworks don't allow UI modification from non-main (non-UI) thread. So, you should use [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to post updates to the UI thread loop (or [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute delegate in async way). With `TPL` everything is pretty simple:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //long-running stuff
    }).ContinueWith((result) =>
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Please also note, that the question you asked is actually too broad, and it's better to read some articles on executing tasks in async way in `WinForms`.

**EDIT**

If you have no control over `foo`, your code may look like this:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = foo(...);
    Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, (result) =>
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, nikis, My only challenge is that I have no control over the `foo()` method that returns an `IAsyncResult` / takes, as a parameter an `AsyncCallback`. Could TPL still work with that being the case?

Comment: @JohnBustos yes, you can create tasks from `APM`, take a look on my edit

Comment: Thank you so much, Nikis!! - I'm looking into how to implement this now, but that does make sense!!

Comment: SOO sorry, but this still leaves the main question that I had - In my form class, I'm running the `RunOnSeparateThread` method which exists in a separate class - THAT method calls `foo()` and uses the `AsyncCallback` for disposal within that class. How do I now also have an `AsyncCallback` on my form too? That was the main issue....

Comment: Nikis... I GOT IT!!! - I simply change the `public void RunOnSeparateThread()` to `public IAsyncResult RunOnSeparateThread()` and then got to do both.... Thank you!!!!